# Set date format with timezone offset

Tags: javascript, date, extjs, timezone-offset

I have a date value of "09/03/2014 20:49:41 +05:00". How can I format it in order to show it on a date type of field/column?

Comment: [The docs are here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.Date).  What specifically have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Very new to Ext JS. Thanks for the link. It isn't in ext js 4 doc. Now, I tried to set the format to be 'm/d/Y H:i:s P' and result is 09/03/2014 20:49:41 -04:00. And all dates have the same datetimeoffset - -04:00. Is it using machine's timezone data? Is P the correct formatter to use?

Comment: Same URL for v4, just change the version.  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Date

Comment: Regarding offset, it would appear to not preserve the input offset, thus using the offset of the machine that it is running on.  I don't see a way around this in Ext.js.  You might want to look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) and its `parseZone` function.